# Why am I losing properties on JSON.stringify() method?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

I started noticing this more recently over the past few months and I'm not sure what the cause of it is.  I'm creating objects that get pushed to an array.  After all objects get pushed to the array, with the same properties, I use the JSON.stringify method to convert it into a json string so that I can insert that array of objects into my db.  The problem that I've noticed is that some of these objects are missing properties that should be there.

Here is part of my file that pertains to this question

```js
AddPartHandler(){
let items = this.state.ItemList;
let part = this.state.ItemSelected;

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
                if(items[i].ItemName == part){

                    var ItemToPush = {
                        ID: items[i].ID,
                        Quantity: 1,
                        Serial: "No"
                    }

                    //console.log(ItemToPush);
                    listToPush.push(ItemToPush);

this.setState({ListToPush: listToPush});

}
```

After my list is complete, I then get it ready and send to my db like so

```js
AddBuildHandler(){

        let partName = this.state.PartName;
        let partsArray = this.state.ListToPush;
        let array = [];
        let todaysDate = new Date();
        todaysDate = (todaysDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + todaysDate.getDate() + "-" + todaysDate.getFullYear()
        let lastId = parseInt(this.state.LastID);
        lastId = lastId + 1;

        //console.log(JSON.stringify(partsArray));

        var ItemObject = {
            PartName: this.state.AssemblyName,
            Type: "Assembly Item",
            Category: "Parts",
            Units: "unit",
            IsBulk: "FALSE",
            Location: this.state.Location,
            DateCreated: todaysDate,
            CreatedBy: this.state.User,
            PartList: JSON.stringify(partsArray),
            ReorderNumber: "",
            ModelNumber: "",
            Price: "",
            Description: "",
            Serial: "",
        }

        socket.emit('insertNewBuildItem', ItemObject, (boolean) => {
            if(!boolean){
                alert('Could not create Assembly Item');
            }
        });
```

if I do a console log after the stringify method, I get something like this

```js
{ID: 325, Serial: "No", Quantity: 1}, {ID: 302, Serial: "No", Quantity: 1}
```

but sometimes what shows up in my db is like this

```js
{ID: 325, Quantity: 1}, {ID: 302, Serial: "No", Quantity: 1}
```

Here is my db sequence just in case anyone needs it

```js
export const insertNewBuildItem = (ItemObject) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(ItemObject.PartList))

            const insertNewBuildItem = `INSERT INTO dispatch_console.inventory_items (ItemName, Type, Category, IsBulk, DateCreated, Createdby, PartNumber, ModelNumber, Description, Serial, Units, ReorderNumber, PartList, Location) VALUES ('${ItemObject.PartName}', '${ItemObject.Type}', '${ItemObject.Category}', '${ItemObject.IsBulk}', '${ItemObject.DateCreated}', '${ItemObject.CreatedBy}', '${ItemObject.PartNumber}', '${ItemObject.ModelNumber}', '${ItemObject.Description}', '${ItemObject.Serial}', '${ItemObject.Units}', '${ItemObject.ReorderNumber}', '${ItemObject.PartList}', '${ItemObject.Location}');`;

            const response = await db(insertNewBuildItem, "Inserting New Item to Build List");
            resolve(response);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR inventory.insertNewBuildItem: " + e);
            reject(e);
        }
    });
};
```

I have plenty of other places in my code where I do this exact same thing and don't have any of these issues, so it's kind of mind boggling as to where this is omitting properties randomly.  If anyone has any ideas or suggestions that would help me a bunch. Thanks!

Comment: Try debugging and see what are the lost values. `JSON.stringify` will omit `undefined`

Comment: Now that you say that, I think I know the reason for why this is happening lol.

Comment: It will also omit `function`s and `Symbol`s